# React testing library - await findBy* vs promise.then

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a test where I await for some text to be shown:
`const allTodosPromise = findByText('All Todos')`

My test actually checks if the HTMLElement returned has some style (to see if it is active or not):

`expect(await allTodosPromise).toHaveStyle(activeItemStyle);`
which fails with message "Unable to find an element with the text 'All Todos'...".

But, if I resolve my promise with a `then` the test passes, like:

```
   allTodosPromise.then(htmlElement => 
       expect(htmlElement).toHaveStyle(activeItemStyle)
   );
```

Why? And yes, I did say that my test function is `async`.

Also trying to await in the first reference fails:
`const allTodosElement = await findByText('All Todos');`

Comment: I'd guess that the second version of the test passes because the expectation isn't actually reached before the test ends, rather than because it's reached and doesn't fail. See https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous - you can check by asserting on the number of expectations reached.

Comment: Could you provide the code under test?

Answer (score -1):

You can try the `waitFor` function: https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/#waitfor

Comment: findBy is just a wrapper around waitFor + getBy. already tried, doesn't work